# How to solve this bus error?

Tags: c++, bus-error

The following piece of code worked well in one program and 
caused a bus error in the other

```
    char *temp1;
    temp1=(char*)malloc(2);
    for(b=3;b>=0;b--)
       {
       sprintf(temp1,"%02x",s_ip[b]);
       string temp2(temp1); 
       temp.append(temp2);
       }
```

s_ip[b] is of type byte and temp is a string. What caused this bus error and how can I solve this?
Moreover, what is the reason for this strange behaviour?

Comment: Note that depending on the actual values in s_ip[b] this might write even more than the 2 digits you expect, so you should consider adding some safety by using snprintf

Comment: @sjsam, does `s_ip` have 4 elements ?

Comment: @sjsam, then the only valid indexes for `s_ip` are `0` and `1` but the posted `for` loop will access `3, 2, 1, 0`. Change `for` loop to `for (b = 1; b >= 0; b--)`

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? The SIGBUS should point you right at the problem.

Comment: @rtlgrmpf : That seems a good thing to do..

Comment: @hmjd: sorry I made a mistake ,s_ip is a byte array of **four** elements.
The ouput the above piece of code gave me for one program was `Reversed Source IP -0200a8c0` that is even when I use `temp1=(char*)malloc(2)`

Comment: @sjsam, the fact it works is due to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `temp` buffer must be 3 chars in length as `sprintf()` will append a null terminator after the two hex characters:

```
char temp1[3];
```

There appears to be no reason to be using dynamically allocated memory. Note you can avoid the creation of the temporary `string` named `temp2` by using [`std::string::append()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append):

```
temp.append(temp1, 2);
```

An alternative is to avoid using `sprintf()` and use a `std::ostringstream` with the IO manipulators:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostringstream s;

s << std::hex << std::setfill('0');

for (b = 3; b >= 0; b--)
{
    s << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(s_ip[b]);
}
```

Then use `s.str()` to obtain the `std::string` instance.

Comment: He could even avoid any temporary alltogether by resize()ing the string and then directly writing into it with snprintf...

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I thought that was undefined behaviour?

Comment: @PlasmaHH, can you post the code you mean? If you modify the internals of the `std::string` directly and say it caches its size would the `std::string` instance not be invalidated?

Comment: You just do something N=s.size(); s.resize(N+p); r=snprintf(&s[N],p,blah); s.resize(N+r);. I don't know what you mean by "caching the size"

Comment: I thought that is what you meant. I had always thought this was illegal. If not, then I have learned something today.

Comment: It has inofficially been legal (since no one came up with a way to create a string class that will not support it but is otherwise standards compliant) forever, and officially since C++11.

Answer (score 3):

A string with 2 characters actually needs 3 bytes, because there is also a terminating `'\0'` at the end of the string.

Comment: Thank You. I have changed it but I'm still getting a bus error. Is there any other reasons to get this error??